# Why is assigning my series to the same series without null values not valid?

Tags: python, pandas

1

```
star_wars['id'] = star_wars['id'].dropna()
```

2

```
star_wars['id'].dropna(inplace= True)
```

1 doesn't seem to change anything about the series. 2 works, but I'm wondering why one does not.

Comment: Share more code, and don't clal your variable the same name as the pandas class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are assigning to part of a **`DataFrame`** and this is important because basic assignment to a Series of a DataFrame **cannot change the length** of the DataFrame.

The way assignment works when assigning a Series to a Series of a DataFrame is that it will align on the row-index and update the values. So, `star_wars['id'].dropna()` removes the null-rows, but then when you assign back it will only assign values to the rows where the index overlaps, and `NaN`s the rest. However, because these rows were `NaN` to begin with, it *looks* like *nothing* happened.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2, np.NaN, 3]}) 

#   df           df.dropna()
#   foo             foo
#0  1.0          0  1.0
#1  2.0          1  2.0
#2  NaN                  # Nothing aligns so gets `NaN` but it was already `NaN`
#3  3.0          3  3.0
```

---

It is a bit clearer to see what's going on if we try to assign a simple series where the 0th index row has a value of 7

```
#   df          pd.Series([7], name='foo)
#   foo            foo
#0  1.0          0   7
#1  2.0                 # Nothing aligns so gets `NaN`
#2  NaN                 # Nothing aligns so gets `NaN` but it was already `NaN`
#3  3.0                 # Nothing aligns so gets `NaN` 


df['foo'] = pd.Series([7], name='foo')
print(df)
#   foo
#0  7.0
#1  NaN
#2  NaN
#3  NaN
```

On the other hand `DataFrame.dropna()` **can** change the length of the DataFrame, so it is able to remove rows that have null values on the subset of columns you specify, which is why the second method works.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in either of cases because size of a single column cannot differ from the rest of the rows in dataframe so dropna should be performed as a whole.